# Dataweave - Filter if a field value is null or not

Tags: json, filter, mule, dataweave

I read a file that contains a `JSON Array` like this:

```
[
   {
      "example":{
         "name":"edward",
         "lastName":"espin"
      },
      "error":"That name doesn't exists"
   },
   {
      "example":{
         "name":"toretto",
         "lastName":"brav"
      },
      "error":null
   }
]
```

I want to store in a new file **only the records which the error value is not null** using the same format.

I have used a `for-each` that runs through each JSON and inside, checks if that JSON does not have the "error" field with null value (`payload.error != null`).

The problem is that I use a `for-each` and in a `choice`.

**The output expected must be:**

```
[
   {
      "example":{
         "name":"edward",
         "lastName":"espin"
      },
      "error":"That name doesn't exists"
   }
]
```

Is there a simpler way with a **transformation component** and **Dataweave 2**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is quite simple just use the filter operator in a message transform message processor.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload filter ((item, index) -> item.error != null)
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is another way

```
payload[?($.error != null)]
```